# How was CES utility function derived?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, utility, cobb-douglas, elasticity-of-substitution

Is there any book/papers that I can refer to the proof (derivation) of the CES utility function?

Or if anyone could help me with the derivation, I will be so much grateful to you.

Comment: What do you mean by "derivation"? Finding the derivative? Or obtaining the CES function from some fundamental conditions?

Comment: @HerrK. I wanted to understand how people came up with the CES utility function. Not the derivatives, derivatives are very easy to find.

Comment: Did any of the excellent answers bellow happened to answer your Q? If so consider accepting one of them (ticking the check mark below up/downvote) - it improves site stats and gives you some points as well

Answer (score 7):

To understand the CES utility functions, which I guess is your question, a good starting point is the Wikipedia page on [constant elasticity of substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_elasticity_of_substitution). In particular,

> The CES aggregator is also sometimes called the Armington aggregator, which was discussed by [Armington (1969)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3866403?seq=1).

Then, the CES utility function was popularized by [Dixit and Stiglitz (1977)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1831401?seq=1) in their study of optimal product diversity in a context of monopolistic competition.

If you want to understand how the CES utility function behaves when $\sigma=\infty$ or $\sigma=1$ [here](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/sv/oekonomi/ECON4415/h11/undervisningsmateriale/Lecture8revised3.pdf) is a nice discussion of the basics of the CES utility function, which is widely used in trade.

If you want a deeper understanding of the elasticity of substitution and a discussion of the special class for which the elasticity of substitution is a constant $\sigma$, [here](https://econ.ucsb.edu/%7Etedb/Courses/GraduateTheoryUCSB/elasticity%20of%20substitutionrevised.tex.pdf) is an insightful discussion by Ted Bergstrom.

Answer (score 6):

The C.E.S functional has been introduced in Economics in the context of production theory, by

**Arrow, K. J., Chenery, H. B., Minhas, B. S., & Solow, R. M. (1961). Capital-labor substitution and economic efficiency. The review of Economics and Statistics, 225-250.**

There you can find a discussion of how it was derived.

A more pedagogic and detailed treatment can be found in

**Silberberg, E. (1990). The structure of economics; A mathematical analysis (International Edition), pp. 285-297**